# Substitution variable in Essbase script

Tags: hyperion, essbase

I´m trying use a substitution variable for parametrize my private Key. I have created the substituion variable with the name 'privateKey'.

```
RUNJAVA com.hyperion.calcmgr.common.cdf.MaxLScriptFunction
"-D"
"123456.1234567" /* Private key */ 
""
"login $key 944589711255867592121610891 $key 944589711255867592121610891 on 'localhost'"
"alter database 'MIS'.'Analytic'
clear data in region
'{
.....
} ' physical "
"logout"
"spool off"
"exit";
```

I have tried change in the script for $privateKey but doesn´t work.

```
RUNJAVA com.hyperion.calcmgr.common.cdf.MaxLScriptFunction
    "-D"
    "$privateKey" /* Private key */ 
    ""
    "login $key 944589711255867592121610891 $key 944589711255867592121610891 on 'localhost'"
    "alter database 'MIS'.'Analytic'
    clear data in region
    '{
    .....
    } ' physical "
    "logout"
    "spool off"
    "exit";
```

Can someone help me ?

Thanks in advance

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Hi Laggc – I don't recommend this approach, but if you want to refer to a substitution variable in a MaxL script, you need to use an ampersand. The dollar sign is used fro MaxL variables as well as the special `$key` "meta-variable". So you would need to use `&privateKey%` instead of `$privateKey`.